# Set default country code when creating object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using carr/phone gem for formatting phone numbers.
I set default country code like this.

```
Phoner::Phone.default_country_code = '49'
```

and when I want to create an object

```
normalized_number = Phoner::Phone.new(:number => number, :area_code => area, :country_code => intl)
```

I get an error:

```
Phoner::CountryCodeError: Must enter country code or set default country code
```

When using .parse I don't get this error but I need an object. Anyone know how to set default_country_code when creating an object? I tried to send :default_country_code param but didn't work.

Comment: what  is the value of `intl` `:country_code => intl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clear that if `country_code is nil` . It will throw this error

Please refer https://github.com/carr/phone/blob/1a326c0f344b7dc1b6d39c80b3042620322c71e9/lib/phone.rb#L142

So you can do simply one thing

```
normalized_number = Phoner::Phone.new(:number => number, :area_code => area, :country_code => intl) unless country_code.nil?
```